# Sliding Panels, Multiple screen, iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am working on app that has a sliding pnel ( like facebook or google+ app). I have one main settings menu that I've already built for one part of the app.
I can implement any of the github prjects like JASidePanels, the problem I have is that I need the sliding settings menu to appear on different parts of the app, and that sliding settings menu has to be the same. I canresolve this by building for every ViewController its own sliding settings menu, but I wanted to ask how do other people do this? is there a way to create only one instance of that sliding settings menu and use it in different parts of the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use ZUUIRevealController.

[ZUUIRevealController](https://github.com/pkluz/ZUUIRevealController)

You can get this to bring your menu up on any viewcontroller

I use this piece of code on every view I want the menu to appear (I am using UINavigationController but you may be able to rework it to not use UINavigationController if that is required). This code is placed in the viewDidLoad

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];


if ([self.navigationController.parentViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(revealGesture:)] && [self.navigationController.parentViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(revealToggle:)])
    {
            UIPanGestureRecognizer *navigationBarPanGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.navigationController.parentViewController action:@selector(revealGesture:)];
            [self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:navigationBarPanGestureRecognizer];

            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:detail.menuTitle style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self.navigationController.parentViewController action:@selector(revealToggle:)];
    }
```

**EDIT** - There is now a new version called PKRevealController that has replaced ZUUIRevealController

[PKRevealController](https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController)

Comment: Looks interesting, but the code seems a bit old, and not a lot of documentation. Are you using in iOS 7?

Comment: Yes it is old I think it was around iOS5 that I started using it. I am using it in iOS7 on one project

Comment: There is a link on the repository README that refers to PKRevealController which seems to be the more up to date version. I have updated my answer with a link

Comment: Thanks, will look into the new version.

Comment: Hi Adam, For this code you posted, how do you actually inject the PKrevealController?  I am using storyboards.